# corners not rounded in ie9 but works in other browers

Tags: internet-explorer, css

Below is my code to round the top two corners of a header using css. IE is driving me nuts. My page looks fine on all other browsers. I thought that curved corners are supported on IE9

```
<style type="text/css">
#header {
    height: 70px;
    font-size: 2em;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 40px 0 0 40px;
    background: #0B3A68 no-repeat 15px 11px;
    position: relative;
    font-style: italic;
    font-family: Arial;

    border-top-left-radius: 40px;
    border-top-right-radius: 40px;
}
</style>


<div id ="header">
    test
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a border generator, it may help:

http://border-radius.com/